# Customizing igraph

Tags: r, customization, igraph

I have an undirected weighted network graph generated that looks like this:

[image]

However, it does not look neat, can the nodes be arranged in a circular fashion to make it look more tidy and clear? Also is there any way to increase the size of legend and make it appear at the center bottom?

The R code for this is as follows:

```
library(igraph)
setwd('C:/Users/malsa876/Desktop/RTest')
    a <-c(33,6,5,5,6,1,2,1,0,4,2,4,1,2,2,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,2,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
    class(a)
    dim(a) <- c(8,8)
    #l <-layout.reingold.tilford(g) 
    a
    # create igraph object.
    g <- graph.adjacency(a, mode="undirected", weighted=TRUE)
    V(g)$label.cex <- 0.5
    V(g)$name<-c("OD", "ACC", "SI", "T", "RD","SCA", "RU", "CC")
    plot(g,main = 'Network Analysis of Interlinked Dimensions',edge.label=round(E(g)$weight, 3),vertex.label = V(g)$name)
    legend("bottomright", c("OD - Operational Demonstration", "ACC - Accuracy", "SI - Stakeholders Interests",  "T - Time", "RD - Requirements Dependency","SCA - Scalability","RU - Requirements Updates","CC - Computational Complexity"),cex=0.5,title = 'Legend')
    V(g)$label.cex <- 0.5
    V(g)$name<-c("OD", "ACC", "SI", "T", "RD","SCA", "RU", "CC")
    d<-V(g)$label
    E(g)$width <- E(g)$weight + min(E(g)$weight) + 1 # offset=1
    plot(g,main = 'Network Analysis of Parameters',edge.label=round(E(g)$weight, 3),vertex.label = V(g)$name)
    legend("bottomright", c("OD - Operational Demonstration", "ACC - Accuracy", "SI - Stakeholders Interests",  "T - Time", "RD - Requirements Dependency","SCA - Scalability","RU - Requirements Updates","CC - Computational Complexity"),cex=0.5,title = 'Legend')
```

Comment: Although I don't have time for a complete answer right now, I have found that `visNetwork` and `sigmaNet` are much better at producing visually appealing networks. Would suggest looking at those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by building your own layout.

First to get a purely circular layout you  can use:

```
LO1 = matrix(c(cos((0:7)*2*pi/8), sin((0:7)*2*pi/8)),ncol=2)
plot(g,main = 'Network Analysis of Parameters', layout=LO1)
    edge.label=round(E(g)$weight, 3),vertex.label = V(g)$name)
legend("bottomright", c("OD - Operational Demonstration", 
    "ACC - Accuracy", "SI - Stakeholders Interests",  
    "T - Time", "RD - Requirements Dependency",
    "SCA - Scalability","RU - Requirements Updates",
    "CC - Computational Complexity"),cex=0.5,title = 'Legend', 
    bty="n")
```

[image: Circular graph]

Notice that I used `bty="n"` to make a little extra room for the legend.  But that only leaves a little room for the legend. Another way is to leave some extra space *in the layout* for the legend at the lower right. Then you can make the font a little bigger.

```
LO2 = matrix(c(cos((0:7)*2*pi/9), sin((0:7)*2*pi/9)),ncol=2)
plot(g,main = 'Network Analysis of Parameters', layout=LO2,
    edge.label=round(E(g)$weight, 3),vertex.label = V(g)$name)
legend("bottomright", c("OD - Operational Demonstration", 
    "ACC - Accuracy", "SI - Stakeholders Interests",  
    "T - Time", "RD - Requirements Dependency",
    "SCA - Scalability","RU - Requirements Updates",
    "CC - Computational Complexity"),cex=0.7,title = 'Legend', 
    bty="n")
```

[image: Circular graph with an empty space]